# Is it correct to say "Foo objects are used for..." when Foo is an interface

Tags: oop, terminology

It is not possible to create an object out of an interface. Is it still acceptable to say "Foo objects are used for...". Or is it necessary to say something like "Objects of a class implementing Foo are used for.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to say “Foo objects are used for…” when Foo is an interface

### No

As is already in the question:

> It is not possible to create an object [instance] out of an interface.

Where Foo is an interface, saying "Foo objects are used for" can be read/understood to mean:

- It *is* possible to instanciate the Foo interface
- Objects of classes implementing the Foo interface

There's implicit reliance on the reader discounting the first statement, and understanding the second. It's best **not** to rely on such assumptions.

### Objects of a class implementing Foo

> is it necessary to say something like "Objects of a class implementing Foo ..."

This is unambiguous, and is an appropriate way to refer to objects which implment the Foo interface. Personally I'd say:

> Instances of classes implementing the Foo Interface

As it's crystal clear what `Foo` is, and also avoids ambiguity in the case where there's both a `Foo` interface *and* class.

Answer (score 0):

An intefrace simply CANNOT have instances, **not even if it is implemented by a class** (as suggested in some answeres).

If a class implements an interface, that does not change the fact that the interface cannot have instances. This will only create "a contract" with the class, as interface is a set of features (properties and methods). Instances of this class **are still class instances** (or objects) and not interface instances.

Interface can only be implemented or used to reference the instances of classes that implement it. Interface is a kind of Type.

**There is no such a concept as "interface instance"**.

An extract from the UML spec:

> Interfaces may not be instantiated. Instead, an Interface
>   specification is implemented or realized by a BehavioredClassifier,
>   which means that the BehavioredClassifier presents a public facade
>   that conforms to the Interface specification.

"Interfaces may not be instantiated" is just another way of saying "interfaces does not have instances".

As a kind of UML Type, an interface can be used to access the instances of the classes that implement it. So, you can define a variable of the Type that is interface. However, you must instanciate a corresponding class to get an instance and assign a reference to it to the variable.

In pseudo-language:

```
Interface I;

Class C extends I;

I var = new C;    // valid instantiation of the class C!
I var2 = new I;   // this will clearly not work.
```

Comment: While you're technically correct I think this is an overly pedantic destinction. An instance of a class implementing an interface is an instance implementing an interface. Infact, having re-read the question -1 as your only ranting about the other answers and don't actually provide an answer `Or is it necessary to say something like ... <what?>`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'X instanceof Foo', hence you can say 'Foo objects'...

Comment: No, you cannot (downvote), please see other comments and my answer.

Comment: I disagree, the issue is not 'can i instanciate an interface' but rather ' can I reffer to implementors of an i terface and call them 'objects'... I think we all agree on the facts: interface cannot be instaciated but can have an implementor with objects, hence, since its 'son' is an 'instanceof' the interface we can reffer to the objects of the interface

Comment: Informally, you can probably say whatever you want, eventhough it is very incorrect. You say "you can use 'X instanceof Foo', hence you can say 'Foo objects'..." So, you start from a wrong statement ('X instanceof Foo) to make a wrong conclusion. If this is not misleading, I don't know what is.

Comment: If X implements Foo than instanceof will return true, you may disagree but it will still  be true...what is wrong with this statement?